# android listview addHeaderView center

Tags: android, android-listview

i have listview, i add headerview to listview. but it is not center and **i don't want to create a layout headerview**. can you help me?
It is code :

```
  //add header view
        final ImageView headerView = new ImageView(getActivity());
        headerView.setLayoutParams(new AbsListView.LayoutParams((int) CommonUtil.convertDpToPixel(151,
                                                                                                  getActivity()),
                                                                (int) CommonUtil.convertDpToPixel(20,
                                                                                                  getActivity())));
       headerView.setPadding(0,
                             10,
                             0,
                             10);
        headerView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_powered_by_foursquare);

        mLvVenueTips.addHeaderView(headerView);
```

it is main xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_venue_tips_background"
        style="@style/CreateTrips.Widget.BackgroundImage"
        android:contentDescription="@null"/>

    <!-- The Action Bar -->
    <com.createtrips.ui.widgets.ActionBar
        android:id="@+id/ab_venue_tips"
        style="@style/CreateTrips.Widget.ActionBar"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lv_venue_tips"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/widget_action_bar_height"
        android:divider="@color/transparent_white_percent_10"
        android:layout_gravity="center|top"
        android:dividerHeight="@dimen/widget_divider_height"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

it is Model xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:paddingRight="15dp"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_tips_message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:text="@string/text_drunken_translate"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_light_medium"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_name_user_send_and_date_tip"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_tips_message"
        android:text="@string/text_name_of_the_user_send_the_tip_and_date_format"
        android:textColor="@color/text_secondary"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_extra_small"/>


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_drunken_translate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_tips_message"
        android:background="@color/transparent"
        android:text="@string/text_drunken_translate"
        android:textColor="@color/text_primary"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_extra_small"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

It is image result :
[image]

**i want imageview "POWEREB BY FOURSQUARE" is center**
[image]

Comment: Isn't this causing some trouble? headerView.setPadding(0,10,0,10);

Comment: share headerview xml

Comment: Smulian : i remove  headerView.setPadding(0,10,0,10) but it is not resolution

Answer (score 0):

Set gravity for headerView and it should be centered aligned.
Instead of using

```
headerView.setLayoutParams(new AbsListView.LayoutParams((int) CommonUtil.convertDpToPixel(151, getActivity()), (int)CommonUtil.convertDpToPixel(20,getActivity())));
```

Use this:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams((int) CommonUtil.convertDpToPixel(151, getActivity()), (int)CommonUtil.convertDpToPixel(20,getActivity());
params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.TOP
headerView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: it have not : headerView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.TOP); and headerView.gravity = Gravity.CENTER.

Comment: Sorry but didn't get you. You mean didn't worked this at all?

Comment: Edited comment, plz check now.

Comment: but when   mLvVenueTips.addHeaderView(headerView); It is error when use LinearLayout.LayoutParams.

Comment: debugs:android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.AbsListView$LayoutParams

Answer (score 0):

i resolution sucess:

```
RelativeLayout linearLayout = new RelativeLayout(getActivity());
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getActivity());
    imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_powered_by_foursquare);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params =
            new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams((int) CommonUtil.convertDpToPixel(151,
                                                                            getActivity()),
                                          (int) CommonUtil.convertDpToPixel(20,
                                                                            getActivity()));
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT,
                   RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(params);
    linearLayout.setLayoutParams(new AbsListView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                                              ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    linearLayout.addView(imageView);
    mLvVenueTips.addHeaderView(linearLayout);
```